# replicate `npm pack` and allow for streaming to stdout

Tags: npm, tar

The `npm pack` command only allows you to write out a file to the current working directory.

I am looking for a way to do this:

`npm pack > $myfile`

So I am considering writing my own version of npm pack  - but I dont quite know how it's implemented.

Does anyone know if `npm pack` as its currently implemented bundles node_modules? is there some quick and dirty way to replicate its functionality but write output to stdout?

I assume npm pack is based on the tar command and that the tar command allows you to write to stdout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `yarn` instead of rewriting `npm`

```
yarn pack -f some/other/path.tgz
```

or if you really need to redirect:

```
yarn pack -f /dev/stdout > some/other/path.tgz
```